# How do I loop data on my GUI in Java?

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

```
private void enterData() {
    numberOfCars = 10; // the maximum number of cars to be examined will be no more than 10
    carRegistration = registrationField.getText(); // car registration is what users type in the registration field
    carAge = Integer.parseInt((String) ageCombo.getSelectedItem()); // the age is to be selected from the combo box
    boolean accident = accidentCheckBox.isSelected(); // the accident status depends on whether or not the checkbox is ticked
    discount = Fee * 0.25; // declaring that the discount is 25% of the fee

    textArea.setText(String.format("%10s %10s %10s %10s", "Registration", "Age", "Accident", "Fee\n")); // placing the headings of the four categories of information into text
    textArea.append(String.format("--------------------------------------------\n")); // underline separates the titles of categories from the information of each car
    textArea.append(String.format("%10s %10s %10s %10s", carRegistration, carAge, Accident, "$" +Fee)); // the four categories information displayed into text for each car

    if(accidentCheckBox.isSelected()) // if the accident checkbox is displayed, the accident status should display as YES
       Accident = "YES";
    else
       Accident = "NO"; // if the accident checkbox is displayed, the accident status would display as NO

    if(numberOfCars > 10)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have reached the limit of cars to enter"); // display error message if the number of cars exceed 10

    if (carAge > 5)
      Fee = 350.00; // if the car is above 5 years of age, the fee would be $350.00

    if(carAge<=5)
      Fee = 200.00; // if the car is under or equal to 5 years of age, the fee would be $200.00

    if(accidentCheckBox.isSelected())
        Fee = Fee; // if the car has been in an accident, the fee will not change
    else
        Fee = Fee - discount; // if the car has not been in an accident, the fee will be discounted

    if(registrationField.getText().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a car's registration"); // error message if car registration isn't entered
    }

    registrationField.setText(""); // reset the registration field when data is entered

    ageCombo.setSelectedIndex(0); // reset the combo box to the default number selected when data is entered

    accidentCheckBox.setSelected(false); // reset the check box to its default state when data is entered

    registrationField.requestFocus();
} // enterData
```

I want to loop the text for `carRegistration`, `carAge`, `Accident` and `Fee`, I am tasked to enter those details for at least 10 cars, however on the GUI only one line is active for text, if I were to enter new data its text will just replace the one I previously typed in, I want it to be entered on a new line.

Comment: sorry, no offense, but i can't understand the question... can you rephrse what you want to do? maybe someone can help you with translation, but i don't get it ...

Comment: If you want 10 lines (TextAreas), Just add 10 of it! You can loop to create them.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting text via `textArea.setText()`. Do it only once before the loop or create a boolean flag and set it to true when you set a text to text area and check it everytime in the loop before you trying to set it again.